# How does one pass arguments from the URL to a view before rendering a new page?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a stock portfolio app. The user has a list of stocks each of which has a link which looks something like 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/symbol=TSLA'. What I want to do is pass the stock symbol 'TSLA' to one of my views and simply print that string on the next page (for now).

What I have done so far (did not include it in the code below) is to simply have some method in my `SearchPageView` called `get_symbol` and I tried to get the url from there and in my `search.html` template, I tried accessing that via `{{ view.get_symbol }}`. But this displays nothing.

My set-up:

**views.py:**

```
class SearchPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import SearchPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/<string>', SearchPageView.as_view(), name='search_stock'),
]
```

**search.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I know there's nothing above, all i'm asking for is how to pass the string 'TSLA' to my view then to 'search.html' then I can do what I need to do with it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I need more clarification. Do you want something like `your_url/symbol=SOMETING` return objects that match with `SOMETHING`?

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon yup, basically from the url, `SOMETHING` is passed to one of my functions in views.py then I show it in my template `search.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `urls.py` by this

```
path('search/<symbol>', SearchPageView.as_view(), name='search_stock'),
```

In `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView


class SearchPageView(ListView):

        template_name = 'your_template.html'

        def get_queryset(self):
            self.publisher = get_object_or_404(YOUR_MODEL_NAME, name=self.kwargs['symbol'])
            return YOUR_MODEL_NAME.objects.filter(symbol=self.symbol)
```

I consider your model field name is `symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def page_view(request):
    # recheck how to get data you want pass in html from this view
    return render(request, 'search.html', {
            'symbol': request.DATA.get('symbol'),
    })
```

and in url change to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/<string>', page_view, name='search_stock'),
]
```

and in `search.html` you will have `{{ symbol }}` variable from `def page_view`